# How to control Gazebo from a C++ code

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In [this question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7867/joint-created-in-runtime-is-not-working-properly/) there is a cpp code that creates a joint in Gazebo.
How does this cpp code even know how to connect to Gazebo server? and what should be included?
What does a code look like that can connect to the Gazebo server and do some modifications?

I couldn't find any tutorial about the Gazebo Cpp API.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8982/how-to-control-gazebo-from-a-c++-code/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

- [Gazebo's C++ API](http://gazebosim.org/api)
- [Tutorial's about writing plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin)
- [Code examples](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/examples/)

The most common way to communicate with the Gazebo server is to write a plugin (see link above). You can also write your own [custom main](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/examples/stand_alone/custom_main/).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1