# Use Gazebo API to connect to already running simulation

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

My setup consists of two elements:

1. A launch file that brings Gazebo up from a given SDF file.
2. An executable that makes use of the Gazebo API and modifies `Entity`s properties.

In this executable, I'd like to somehow connect to the existing simulation and get its `EntityComponentManager` so I can modify the properties of an `Entity`, such as its visibility, position and velocity. From the API documentation, I guess this may be done using either the [`Server`](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/6/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1Server.html) or [`SimulationRunner`](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/src/SimulationRunner.hh) classes. However, I'm not sure exactly how. I'd appreciate if someone provided a snippet that e.g. connects to a simulation and prints the names of the loaded entities.

From [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/how-to-control-gazebo-from-a-c-code):

> The most common way to communicate with the Gazebo server is to write a plugin

The reason I'm trying not to use plugins is that I would need to interface with them via topics. For instance, the executable would publish to the `/toggle_entity_visibility` topic, the plugin would subscribe to it and perform the corresponding actions in the callback.

Apart from that, topics don't give direct feedback on weather the requested task has been accomplished. Services do, but in the moment of posting this questions [almost any service](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/humble/ros_gz_bridge#bridge-communication-between-ros-and-gazebo) is bridged to ROS 2.

I'd like to avoid that and create a library that interfaces with the `Entity`s via memory pointers. This solution seems simpler to me, but perhaps there are some points or tradeoffs I'm not taking into account. If that's the case, please feel free to let me know!

I'm using Ubuntu Jammy, ROS 2 Humble and Ignition Gazebo Fortress.